# How to creat a checkbox with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to display several options to my user and that he can choose one or more otions

**I want upload the check in my bdd**

this is idea of the form

```
#views/values/new.html.erb*

<% @values =["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
<%= form_for @resultvalue do |f| %>
   <% @values.each do | value | %>
       <%= f.check_box :values, { multiple: true }, value, false %>
       <%= f.label value %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit%>  
<% end %>
```

```rb
#controller/resultvalue_controller.rb

class ResultvaluesController < ApplicationController
[...]
 def resultvalue_params
     params.require(:resultvalue).permit(:values)
 end
end
```

```rb
#models/resultvalue.rb

class Resultvalue < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :values, Array 
end
```

My question is about  the controller, I don't know what to write to send the data to my database if the choice is multiple

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these variants:

```
<% @values = ["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
<% @values.each do |value| %>
```

or

```
<% values = ["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
<% values.each do |value| %>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question is more about controllers, I don't know what to write to send the data to my database if the choice is multiple

Answer (score 0):

This is a short and simple way if your array is short.

```
["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"].each do |value|%>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<%= value %>" name="<%= value %>">
    <label for="<%= value %>"><%= value %></label>
  </div>
<% end %>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
  Validate
</button>
```

Otherwise, you can create a constant under your model or any other module such as:

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  CHOICES = ["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"].freeze 
end
```

And then inside your view, you use the constant as in:

```
ModelA::CHOICES.each do |value|%>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<%= value %>" name="<%= value %>">
    <label for="<%= value %>"><%= value %></label>
  </div>
<% end %>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
  Validate
</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my question is more about controllers, I don't know what to write to send the data to my database if the choice is multiple

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems.

1. Choose which variable you want to use: @values or values.
2. You do not need = in the first line, unless you want to make it visible on the view.

```
    <%= values =["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
    <% @values.each do |value|%>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="<%= value %>" name="<%= value %>">
        <label for="<%= value %>"><%= value %></label>
      </div>
     <% end %>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
        Validate
    </button>
```

This will make your view work.

After this, you need to have form, which will post to the corresponding controller action.

After that, you can save your data in the controller from parameters, just like: User.update(power: params[:Power])

I suggest to take a look at this:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

This is one of the best places to start:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails

Comment: thank you, I fixed the first two problems, these errors were only on this forum because I simplified my real code to highlight only my problem, 
so I made mistakes of carelessness.
Nevertheless I updated my question and removed the different errors and when I subbit, the checkbox data does not send to my bdd. 
my controller is as follows: 
 ````class ResultvaluesController < ApplicationController 
 def resultvalue_params
     params.require(:resultvalue).permit(:values)
 end
end
````